# Tinymce 4.5.5 doesn't visualize images in editor

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I have this problem when insert a image in tinymce editor (images shows like a empty square)  -> 
[tinymce 4.5.5 image vizualize like a small empty square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOgSe.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that is an image? It looks similar to the character that represents an unsupported emoji.

If emojis are not rendering correctly in the editor, it is like a text encoding issue, but would require more information to explore and troubleshoot.

Comment: I solved the problem with adding 'default-src * blob:'  into  header("Content-Security-Policy: default-src * blob: 'self')